# Affix LED to a case

Tags: led, cases, glue

I found a topic related to my problem but I want to consider other options. ([What type of glue do I use on an LED?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18228/what-type-of-glue-do-i-use-on-an-led))

I want to attach LEDs and connectors on the front panel of a box (aluminum). The connectors don't have any holes to affix them. The previous topic talks about gluing. But is it the correct way to attach an LED to a box?

The PCB will be something like 10cm away from the hole, would a glued LED with two wires seem to be enough for you?

Isn't there some kind of LED mount on which I can solder the LED and affix the mount to the case?

Comment: Couldn't you use a screw mount or a press-fit mount?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear whether you want to attach LEDs to the exterior of the enclosure or have them mounted in holes in the aluminum. Typically you would mount them in holes, and to secure them properly, you should consider an LED mount:

[image: LED Mount Image]

At left shows how the LED is secured in the housing. At right shows the mount components separately. It's just a plastic holder which is held in place with a ring.

Look for "LED mounts" at your electronics supplier, there should be a variety to choose from to fit your LED and enclosure thickness.

Answer (score 3):

One method is to use a bezel LED clip

[image]

These are push-fit

Answer (score 1):

Alternate method - To make LEDs vandal-proof on heavy use timing monitors having 1/8" aluminum front panels the T_1-3/4 LEDs and their panel holes were threaded to 12-24 NC for mounting. This method is suitable for one-off projects with 1/8" panels, is labor intensive and requires ingenuity to thread the LEDs. For threading LEDs the die and LED must be preheated with a hot air gun to reduce the torque necessary for threading and to keep the LED from cracking. You'll have to devise your own method to hold the heated LED during threading.

Answer (score 0):

For the neatest finish just use panel mounting LEDs - there are a wide variety of colours and styles available from suppliers. Terminate the leads with a 2 pin connector or use more pins if you have several LEDs and don't want a separate connector for each.

Here's just one example:

[image: Here's just one example]